# MySQL select in time interval

Tags: mysql

I need to select values in **time** (not timestamp) interval (e.g. +/- 30 minutes).
My example DB consists of 2 cols: text(VARCHAR(100)) and time(TIME).

Now i'm using such syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE time BETWEEN SUBTIME(CURTIME(), "0:30:00") AND ADDTIME(CURTIME(), "0:30:00")
```

But I think it's not optimal because on each row it executes CURTIME(), SUBTIME(), ADDTIME(). Any way to optimize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't actually execute the function for each row because you are performing the function on CURTIME().  It will calculate it once and use it for all rows, as if you had put the exact time in yourself.

You will only have the problem of calculating each row if the function operations on a column (such as time).  So basically you've done this correctly.